# Create an index on the non-used field for the cars collection. mongodb NoSql

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql, boolean

I have a field that uses boolean values for the used cars.  how can I index `used: false`?

```js
db.cars.createIndex({ model: 1, used:-1 })
```

would this be correct syntax to show non used cars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually depends on the queries you perform and the distribution of boolean values of the `used` field.
Generally speaking, if you usually query both fields like this :

```js
db.cars.find({ model: ..., used: false });
```

This index would do the job. It does not matter if you index `used: -1` or `used: 1` since sort does not really apply here.

```js
db.cars.createIndex({ model: 1, used: 1 })
```

But bear in mind that if your boolean values distribution is equal, i.e. 50% `true` and 50% `false`, the index over a boolean field will not boost your query. However, if you primarily look for `used: false` and most of your documents in the DB have this field as `false`, then the index will improve your query time.